# AttributeError: module 'keras._tf_keras.keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

i'm new to tensorflow and keras and i'm trying to build a realtime sign detection model.
I'm following Nicholas Renotte's video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDXdlXlaCco&t=864s

```
import os
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
```

by running this code i'm getting error:
AttributeError: module 'keras._tf_keras.keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental'

please explain to me how to fix this!

i installed tensorflow and keras version 2.15.0

Comment: Could please share the line that is importing `experimental` to check how the import is being done?